# Given array of string contain X number of words return the same word for a given day

Tags: python, java, arrays, string, algorithm

**Background**

My Objective is I am basically trying to create an end point where a user calls the `get_word()` function and they get back a word. The requirement is every single user that calls the `get_word()` function should get back the same word on a given day. No words should repeat until we have cycled through all the words.

So for example let's assume we have a array of words.

`words = ["lebron","kobe","jordan","durant","pipen"]`

**day 1** and users call the function `get_word()` they get back `lebron`

**day 2** and users call the function `get_word()` they get back `kobe`

**day 3** and users call the function `get_word()` they get back `jordan`

**day 4** and users call the function `get_word()` they get back `durant`

**day 5** and users call the function `get_word()` they get back `pipen`

**day 6** and users call the function `get_word()` they get back `lebron`

**day 7** and users call the function `get_word()` they get back `kobe`

The **goal** is to have list of **500 unique words** and on a given day every user should get the same word back. I would also want the ability to add more words in the future.

**Solution**

One very naive solution i am able to think of is i can generate a dictionary with everyday of the year as a key and words as the value. The issue with this is we only have 365 days in a year so i can only store 365 words but not 500.

I appreciate any thoughts or feedback on how i can come up with a better solution here.

This problem is language agnostic hence the java and python tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of modulo and a static date to calculate a growing interval as an index that iterates through the list and loops back to start after it's exhausted.

```
startingDate = "2022-08-25"

words = ["lebron","kobe","jordan","durant","pipen"]

// get the number of days that have passed since the starting date
currentWordIndex = getDaysSince(startingDate) % count(words)

echo words[currentWordIndex] // "lebron" on day 0, "kobe" on day 1, etc.
```

In this example, the words should loop every 5 days.

As you rightly pointed out, using the day of the year limits you to 365 words. Calculating the number of days since the static date helps track an ever-growing interval.

This should work in perpetuity and even allows for the word list to grow, *so long as* you only ever add words to the end. If a word is added somewhere in the middle, "before" the current day's word, it will cause it to change. If you add words to the end, the current word will not change, but the loop back to the start will obviously take longer.

Comment: can you show how your getDaySinceStart function works? i believe you just subtract today's date - start date but just for completion

Comment: What I wrote is obviously pseudo-code. The method is simple arithmetic: Subtract the start date from today's date. Whether you do that using Unix timestamps and calculate days based on difference in seconds, or utilize a built-in method based on your programming language, or use an external library; it's really up to you. In PHP, I would use the Carbon library to do this, because it's so darn useful! In JavaScript, you can use native methods to perform date math.

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of the modulus here.  Assuming the `get_word()` function accepts an integer day index, we can try:

```py
words = ["lebron", "kobe", "jordan", "durant", "pipen"]

def get_words(day):
    return words[(day - 1) % len(words)]  # assuming day starts at 1
```

Comment: oh ! this is cool because i guess modulus let's wrap around.? So input would be any value between and including 1 and 365 right?

Comment: Yes, that will work, _however_ because of leap years and that the array is not a factor of 365, adding 365 days does not guarantee it would generate the same name.

Comment: @Gsinti - does your answer also stumble on leap year it seems like yours does not because you have a start date that is hardcoded and are using another approach to calculate "day" value.

Comment: @Unknowntiou: Correct. My answer will not be affected by leap years, since it's an interval that goes up forever and doesn't care about the current date.

Answer (score 1):

You don't anything fancy apart from a `List` of `String` (or array if you wish, but it is advisable to favor Collections over arrays).

To retrieve a word for a particular day, you need to store a date, which would denote a starting point.

And then you need only to calculate the index of the word based on the number of dates between the current date and start date. For that you can make use of [`ChronoUnit.DAYS.between()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#between(java.time.temporal.Temporal,java.time.temporal.Temporal)).

And to avoid exceeding the size of the list, we need to use modulo operator `%`.

```
List<String> words = List.of(
    "day1", "day2", "day3", "etc"
);
        
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(2022, 1,1);
System.out.println(start);
        
int index = (int) ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, LocalDate.now());
String wordOfDay = words.get(index % words.size());

System.out.println(wordOfDay);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start with an initial date and set that day as day 1. So if day 1 equals 2022.01.05 then 2022.01.07 would be day 3. You can use the modulo operator to get back to day 1 at day 500.